# nuxtjs generate dist subfolder static "static subfolder name" instead of dynamic

Tags: nuxt.js

On "npm run generate" the following folder is generated dynamically on each execution "dist/my-app/static/<dynamic_folder_name>".

Is there a way to force a static name instead?

[image]

Comment: This is mainly used to avoid collision regarding the cache. Why would you remove that? Then you will have to deal on how to invalidate the cache yourself. And your users would be pretty annoyed. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The web app is going to be deployed inside a sitecore cms module, talking to a number of external APIs. Sitecore needs the folders to have static names. However, all data will be re-fetched based on functions.

Comment: The CMS will do something with the files? Usually it's more of the opposite, the Vue files talks to external APIs. There is maybe a way to remove the hash of the directories.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out after digging through the source for the nuxt generator. It seems to be undocumented, but the random number that is used for the static directory is actually a version which is calculated every time (probably for cache breaking).

You can make it the same every time you generate by setting it in your nuxt.config.js:

```
  generate: {
    staticAssets: {
      version: "1",
    },
  }
```

In this case I used "1", but I assume that can be any valid path string.  With a value here, the number won't change from build to build.

Comment: What would be the usage for such feature?

Comment: I use rsync to transfer my dist folder to my static site host, and the random static folder means that the total size on disk continues to grow over time.

Using rsync -d (delete any files on the remote host which don't exist locally) fixes that, but causes another problem: if the old version of the page was still cached, it pointed at a static folder that often wasn't cached, and caused the site to break until the cache got updated.

By having the static folder be predictable, both problems go away. The cache-busting it provides isn't necessary in my use-case.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  build: {
    filenames: {
      app: () => '[name].js',
      chunk: () => '[name].js',
      css: () => '[name].css',
      img: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
      font: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
      video: () => '[path][name].[ext]',
    },
  },
}
```

as [shown here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#filenames) if you want to strip all the hashes from everything.

Comment: This makes all filenames predictable, but it doesn't remove the random number subdirectory from the static directory, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, seems legit otherwise you would not have cache invalidation at all I guess. @mdryden